# How to verify that a .jar or a class has been already loaded by the ClassLoader in Java

Tags: java, web-applications, plugins, jar, classloader

.. i have an application (a .war) which have a plugin system where each pluggable plugin is a .jar with its .jar dependencies.
And in the webapp, via an admin web interface, the plugins are loaded by using the ClassLoader which "loads" the .jar and its dependencies.
But the problem is that, for example, 2 plugins A and B may have one or more common dependencies (commons-io.jar, commons-collection.jar, ...) ... so normally i should not load more that once the .jar which are already loaded by another plugin, or which was already present in the webapp itself -> WEB-INF/lib/
So, i would like to know if there's a way for not loading another time a .jar which was already loaded via the webapp or another plugin
If possible, how must i do it !

Actually, whatever the solution that is available, i just want to avoid classloader issues.

NOTE: each plugin is a .zip file which have into it the following architecture

plugin-name/

```
       - code/

             - A.class

             - B.class

             - ...

       - lib/

            - commons-io.jar

            - log4j.jar

            - ....

       - description.xml

       - version.txt
```

each .class file in the directory code/ are loaded by the classloader, each .jar in the lib/ directory of the plugin is also loaded.

But normally, i should not re-load the classes present in the .jar "commons-io.jar" if ever it was already present ...

I hope i've been clear enough, thanks in advance for paying attention and helping.

Comment: Is it possible that two plugins will require different versions of the same dependency? Or is this not a concern?

Comment: yes it is possible that 2 plugins have different versions of the same dependency

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To trace which classes are loaded by the JVM you could add

```
-verbose:class 
Display information about each class loaded.
```

To your options before starting the JVM.

It wille create an output like

```
[Opened C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Object from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.io.Serializable from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Comparable from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.CharSequence from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.String from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct in understanding you want to know whether a Java file or jar has been loaded or not, if not loaded only then you want to load the it? One solution I get is like you can check whether the classpath has the jar present or not.